# Can someone explain this Perl code snippet?

Tags: perl, file, append, handler

This little piece of code has been a staple in a bunch of my scripts, but I took the syntax from another working script that someone else wrote and adapted it to fit my needs.  I'm not even sure that the syntax used here is the best or most common way to open a file handler either.

The code is:

```
$fh = \*STAT_FILE;
open ($fh,">>".$stat_file) or die "Can't open $stat_file: $!\n";
my $print_flag = ( -z $stat_file );
```

I don't fully understand the first line and also the last line of the code above.  Specifically, `\*STAT_FILE` and `-z`, respectively.

I know that, for the most part, the second line will open a file for appending or quit and throw an error.  But again, I don't understand what purpose the `$!` serves in that line either.

Can someone explain this Perl code, line-by-line, to me in pseudo?  Also, if the method above is not the preferred method, then what is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not using $print_flag anywhere, then remove that line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before perl 5.6, file handles could only be globs (bare words) or references to globs (which is what \*STAT_FILE is). Also, it's better to use 3-argument open ([See the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Also see [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)). So you can now do:

```
open(my $fh, ">>", $stat_file) or die "Failed to open $stat_file: $!";
```

and forget about \*STAT_FILE.

-z is [one of the file test functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (and takes a file name or file handle as an argument) and tests to see if the file has zero size.

$! is one of the [Special Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and contains the most recent system error message (in this case why you can not open the file, perhaps permission issues, or a directory in the path to the file does not exist, etc.).

You should learn to use perldoc, all of this is in perldoc:

perldoc perlfunc (specifically perldoc -f open and perldoc -f -X)

perldoc perlvar

Comment: open(fh, ">>$stat_file) or die "Failed to open $stat_file: $!"; works fine with current as well(but I think my comment is running into the many ways principle of perl)

Comment: @runrig: "You should learn to use perldoc, all of this is in perldoc:" is only helpful if you already knew the (not always so obvious) names of the perl doc page names :)  Good of you to let him know these important ones, though.  :)

Comment: @runrig - thanks for the info and code-cleanup.  @robert P - the point you made is exactly why this question ended up here.  I wasn't sure what to look for in the docs.

Comment: @runrig - what is the whole point of the last line?  why assign that test to `$print_flag`?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: I don't know why the variable is called "$print_flag", maybe it made some sense in some context in the original program. But if you need to refer to that status more than once, assigning it to a variable is more efficient than doing multiple stats. If you don't need that test, don't use it.

Comment: @runrig - thanks.... what would the purpose of it be?  just to check if the file exists before writing/appending to it?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso && @RobertP: I realize that some things are hard to find (especially when you have to look for -z under -X). Basic rule to learn the docs is start with 'perldoc perl' and work your way down the list contained therein.

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: The purpose is to see if the file is empty. I don't know why it's in your program. If you wanted to see if the file exists, you'd use -e BEFORE the open.

Answer (score 3):

The first row assign to the variable a reference (the backslash sign) to the typeglob (a fullsymbol table entry) STAT_FILE. This has been a quite idiomatic perl construct to pass filehandles as reported, just to name it,  in the Larry Wall "Programming perl". The $! variable contains the error message reurned by the operating system.

So the whole meaning is:

- line 1. put in the $fh variable a filehandle;
- line 2. Open for append the file reporting the system message   error should a fault happens;
- line 3.    Set a flag variable warning if the    file has zero length